# Remove the property name from JSON Array in C#

Tags: c#, json

I've a JSON object containing an array like this:

```
{
    "CustRecord": [
        {
            "ID": "40274",
            "Currency": "USD",
            "CustomerNumber": "123456",
            "CustomerName": "contoso"
        },
        {
            "ID": "40275",
            "Currency": "USD",
            "CustomerNumber": "123456",
            "CustomerName": "contoso"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I want to remove the property name "CustRecord" from JSON to create the following output using C#.
How can I achieve this?

```
[
        {
            "ID": "40274",
            "Currency": "USD",
            "CustomerNumber": "123456",
            "CustomerName": "contoso"
        },
        {
            "ID": "40275",
            "Currency": "USD",
            "CustomerNumber": "123456",
            "CustomerName": "contoso"
        }
]
```

Comment: Just serialize the array instead of the object containing the array. It's hard to say any more than that without more context... (It's unclear at the moment whether you're receiving this JSON, or whether you're creating it but want to create something different.) Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var newJson=JObject.Parse(json)["CustRecord"].ToString();
```

or the most efficient way

```
json=json.Substring(0,json.Length-1).Substring(json.IndexOf(":")+1);
```

result

```
[
  {
    "ID": "40274",
    "Currency": "USD",
    "CustomerNumber": "123456",
    "CustomerName": "contoso"
  },
  {
    "ID": "40275",
    "Currency": "USD",
    "CustomerNumber": "123456",
    "CustomerName": "contoso"
  }
]
```

but if you need to deserialize json, not just parse , the best way would be

```
var customerRecord =JObject.Parse(json)["CustRecord"].ToObject<CustomerRecord>();
```

class

```
public class CustomerRecord
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The simple way is to use string manipulation for Json? Sounds like the wrong way to me

Comment: @haldo Tastes differ

Comment: Sure, but best practices don't :P

Comment: @haldo Perfect is the enemy of good

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 6 you can use the new "System.Text.Json.Nodes" namespace. It introduced  [`JsonObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonobject?view=net-6.0) and [`JsonNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode?view=net-6.0).  You can do the following:

```
JsonNode original = JsonObject.Parse(jsonString);
string newJson = original["CustRecord"].ToJsonString();
```

If you want the serialized result to be indented (pretty) Json, then you can pass `JsonSerializerOptions` to `ToJsonString()`:

```
string newJson = original["CustRecord"].ToJsonString(new JsonSerializerOptions 
{ 
     WriteIndented = true 
});
```